# Keyboard shortcut to bring up System Monitor

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I would like to make a keyboard shortcut to bring up the System Monitor - I should be most grateful if someone could let me know how to do this. I am aware of the Custom Settings in the Keyboard (under System Settings) but can't get this to open the System Monitor app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The command you need

If you already found out how to set a custom shortcut: the command you need to set is:

```
gnome-system-monitor
```

#### How to find out the command

To find a command like that is often easy:

- Open the application
- Open a terminal, type `xprop`, click on the application's window. In the terminal output that appears, look for a line like:

  ```
  WM_CLASS(STRING) = "gnome-system-monitor", "Gnome-system-monitor"
  ```

  ...and there we are, often the lower case version is the command to run the application. There are a few other ways though. One is to look into the corresponding `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` and see what (the first) `Exec=` -line sais.